# Sudden spike in number of old late answers up for review

Tags: support, status-bydesign, review

There's been a sudden, massive spike in the number of posts in the Late Answers review queue:

[image: 326 posts in the late answers review queue]

Seems like there's usually only a handful per day, certainly not 300. Most of these answers seem to have been posted several years ago. Some are even community wiki now:

[image: old community wiki answer]

Is this a bug, or is it an intentional effort to clean up old posts that were never reviewed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a network-wide change. See [this Meta.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue) and [this answer to it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267080/572):

> ## Queue growth
>
> Review queues lose effectiveness if posts aren't regularly (and
>   accurately) cleared. A queue such as [close votes on Stack
>   Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251489/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue)
>   that never seems to get to 0 fails to provide time-sensitive feedback
>   that aids learning. So if we raise the bar for late answers which
>   increases the number of tasks going into the queue, we risk making the
>   queue less useful for people answering questions late.
>
> As I write, the Late Answer queue on Stack Overflow is empty. In the
>   last 24 hours the number (non-audit) review tasks of each type added
>   to the queues:
>
> ```
> Review Tasks Type           
> ------------ ----------------- 
> 2467         Triage            
> 2428         First Post        
> 2333         Close Votes       
> 1846         Suggested Edit    
>  883         Low Quality Posts 
>  619         Late Answer       
>  594         Helper            
>  141         Reopen Vote        These two factors suggest that there's room to add more tasks to the Late Answer queue. Assuming we
> ```
>
> raised the reputation limit to 100, we'd add about 300 tasks:
>
> ```
> Rep Bin Tasks 
> ------- ----- 
>  10       417   
>  20       160   
>  30        85    
>  40        76    
>  50        44    
>  60        41    
>  70        37    
>  80        21    
>  90        20    
> 100        20
> ```
>
> You might expect the number of tasks associated with the 1 to 10
>   reputation bin would equal the number of late answer tasks in the last
>   day. The discrepancy stems from reputation earned since answers were
>   added to the queue. But the takeaway is that raising the reputation
>   limit to 100 would add half again as much work to the queue. That
>   doesn't seem particularly onerous.
>
> Not surprisingly, Stack Overflow would see the most added Late Answer
>   reviews by far. Other large sites, such as Ubuntu, Server Fault, Super
>   User and Mathematics, would get 10 or so extra reviews a day.
>
> ### Justifying 100 rather than 50 reputation
>
> Discovering answers as comments certainly would suggest 50 as a good
>   limit for this queue. But this queue is as much about granting
>   exposure to potentially upvote-worthy answers as it is about finding
>   problems. Especially on large sites, it's pretty easy for a good
>   answer to a very old question to be lost in the noise. As a [strategy
>   for new users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/304135/1438) answering
>   old questions that already have good, but not excellent, answers seems
>   productive if not that few people will notice those answers. At 10
>   reputation, a knowledgeable new user has one shot at earning upvotes
>   from excellent answers to aged questions.
>
> ### A potential complication
>
> The one concern I have is that answers are dequeued once the author
>   has reached 100 reputation. If we raise the maximum reputation for
>   going into the queue, we should also raise the minimum for coming out
>   of it. Unfortunately, I don't have an easy way to gather numbers to
>   set an appropriate level. One of the reasons I'm only looking back a
>   day in the numbers I showed above is that it minimizes the effect of
>   gained reputation. It's possible, but messy to estimate reputation at
>   the time a user answered a question. So while my instinct would be to
>   raise the deque minimum to 200, but I can't really predict if that's
>   appropriate or not.
>
> ## Proposal
>
> Raising the bar to 100 would require changing two variables at once.
>   Since that would make it harder to evaluate each individual change,
>   I'd like to try raising the reputation for getting enqueued to the
>   Late Answer reviews to 50 and reconsider upping it to 100 at some
>   point in the future.

Comment: Ah, a network wide change, that would explain why I didn't see anything in meta.programmers. Thanks!